# What's the difference between yield and included template

Tags: meteor

In meteor, you can include a template like this

```
{{> exampleTemplate }}
```

or we can use

```
{{> yield}}
```

another way is

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=example data=this}}
```

So what's the difference? Under what situations should we choose?

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`{{> yield}}` is used to load templates according to defined routes in Iron router for example

`{{> exampleTemplate}}` is used to load a specific template on another template. You can split your templates into different components and load them like that.

`{{> Template.dynamic template=example data=this}}` is used to render a template dynamically. This means that you can code the logic of which template to render in the template helper 'example' in js file.